# Multiple SSL on single IP with virtualmin

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am using Virtualmin (GPL) to manage my servers. I have multiple sites hosted on it binded to single IP address.

I want to enable SSL for multiple servers hosted on it. Can I bind SSL for all such servers via single IP or do I need to purchase IP for each server. Any link to guide, tutorial will be really helpful.

I have already gone through http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/tutorial/how-to-add-multidomain-ssl-certificate which helps me to bind SSL for multiple server but with individual IP.

thanks for reading question, waiting for help on this

Naveen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generaly one SSL certificate is for one domain and binds to one IP address. To have independent SSL certs for each site you will need to purchase additional IP addresses.

However...

If your sites are all subdomains of one main domain name then you could use a wildcard certificate that covers *.example.com. This binds to one IP address but will cover for instance: site1.example.com, site2.example.com

If your other sites use different domain names you can purchase a multi domain SSL certificate (also known as UCC or SAN Certificate) that cover up to 100 different domains. There are some issues with these which may be important depending on your situation. The certificate details list all the other domains covered. This information is only really visible if someone clicks the lock in their browser and checks the certificate details. You cannot change the certificate after purchase so if you want to add or remove domains listed on the cert you will need to purchase a new one (although this varies between certificate suppliers).

Comment: sounds not so good to me :P. My only question is how do hosting providers such as GoDaddy etc can have SSL site hosted on their shared hosting. Do they allocated seperate IP to each website in their shared hosting? I dont believe so, what you think about it ?

Comment: Shared hosting providers are tied to the same SSL hosting rules as everyone else. Just did a quick Google and according to the [GoDaddy FAQs](http://help.godaddy.com/article/1057?ci=5668) "We automatically issue a dedicated IP address when an SSL certificate is installed on our shared hosting servers."

Comment: but then does that mean that website owner need to update their DNS so that their site points to new ip address if I go from non-ssl website to SSL based website ?

Comment: Yes it does, both the SSL and non-SSL version of the site will need to use the same IP address

Comment: Generally one SSL-cert issued *per host*, not domain.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @paul-willis statement

You **can** use different SSL-cert for different hosts on the same IP only if **each** SSL-server will be binded to **different** SSL-ports

Answer (score 2):

What you need is SNI. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication.
AFAIK, Virtualmin does not support setting up SNI in the Virtual Hosts directly. However it tolerates it (there is an option you need to activate to allow multiple SSL sites on one IP, introduced in one of the latest Virtualmin versions). You must set them up manually though.